# How to make Browser Icon Flash in TaskBar on certain event in WebApplication

Tags: c#, jquery, signalr

I am Working with SignalR in a Web application and i want to flash the browser icon to orange in the taskbar when client gets message from Hub.

Code inside Hub.

```
public void PrivateMessage(string UserName, string Message)
{
    Clients.All.newmessage(UserName, Message);
}
```

Response from Hub - Jquery code where message recieved in cshtml page.

```
var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

    chat.client.newmessage= function (UserName,Message) {

     $("#conversation").append('<li>' + UserName + ':' + Message + '</li>');

    };
```

Here after appending Message i want to flash the browser icon if user has minimized the window. Also it should work in all browsers i.e. Chrome, Firefox, Safari.

Thanks in advance. please let me know if anyone has the solution.

Comment: Any solution found? Please share! :)

Comment: No, it was not found and later haven't looked for it. sorry :( But hope if someone will find then will reply here.

Comment: The most polite method to indicate that something changed is to modify your page title.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's alert usually shows that if you put an alert anywhere with a setTimeout.